# android doesn't recognise Resources folder after cleaning the project

Tags: android, eclipse, resources, rjava

Hi I had some errors on my project and tried to clean it but after that now all of my files do not recognise anything that it has to do with the Resources folder. What can I do ? I have more than 20 files with errors now. Please help. Any advice would me much appreciated. Thanks.

Comment: There should be an error in one of the consoles windows. It could be that an error in one of your xml files is causing R.java to not be rebuilt?

Comment: I have no error on my xml files. all the errors that I get are on the java files : R cannot be resolved to a variable. any advice Sir.

Answer (score 1):

An error in one of your resource files will cause R to not get built. That in turn will cause an error in your Java code everywhere a reference to it is made. You may or may not see the error reported in the "Problems" and/or the "Console" windows.

Comment: The thing is that even if I try to create a new blank project it is still doesn't build the R :(